# Is there a way to get list of folders from a datastore in Azure ML studio with Python SDK v2

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-python-sdk

I have a situation where i want to get a list of all the folders from the registered datastore in azure ML studio. We are able to browse the folders in the data section after selecting the particular datastore but i didn't find anyway to see the list programatically in python.
Thanks in advance

I want a iterative list containing the folder names.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get those values using below code.

```
import pandas as pd
from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem

subscription_id = '84412ecc5c0d'
resource_group = 'nonprod-RG'
workspace_name = 'platform'
input_datastore_name = 'ids'
target_datastore_name = 'tds'
path_on_datastore = ''

# long-form Datastore uri format:
uri = f'azureml://subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace_name}/datastores/{input_datastore_name}/paths/{path_on_datastore}'
# instantiate file system using datastore URI
fs = AzureMachineLearningFileSystem(uri)
# list files in the path
f_list = fs.glob()
region_list = []
for f in f_list:
    region_list.append(f.split('/')[1])
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

`fs.ls()` will return a list of all the contents in your blob container (folder in your storage location). I also recommend to read the docs for any updates: [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-interactive?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=adls)

```
from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem

# define the URI - update <> placeholders
uri = 'azureml://subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourcegroups/\
<rg_name>/workspaces/<ws_name>/datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/<blob_name>/'


# create the filesystem
fs = AzureMachineLearningFileSystem(uri)
fs.ls()
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> I want to get a list of all the folders from the registered datastore in Azure ML studio.

Datastores are attached to workspaces and are used to store connection information to Azure storage services
In machine learning, the blob container or file share is the datastores.
Initially, you can see my data stores it has two folders:

[image]

To list the folders only from blob storage(datastores).
you can use the [azure-storage-blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) package and  below code :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str="<Your connection string>"
container_name="your container name(Datastore)"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
for file in container_client.walk_blobs(delimiter="/"):
  print(file.name)
```

**Output:**

The above code is executed successfully, and it returns the folder name only.

```
folder1/
folder2/
```

[image]

If you need to access the folders with files you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str="your connection string"
container_name="containername(datastore)"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
for file in container_client.list_blobs():
    print(file.name)
```

**Output:**

The above code is executed successfully and returns the folder with the file name.

```
folder1/28-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/20-03-2023.html
folder2/sas.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this short helper function does what you want. It only requires the standard azureml Workspace import.

Assuming you have already connected to the AML workspace, and have fetched its default datastore

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace

ws = Workspace.from_config()  # connect to AML workspace

datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
```

What you can do is **(1)** extract the blob service client through the `blob_service` attribute of the datastore; **(2)** connect to the blob container (where datasets in AML are physically stored) with this service client; and **(3)** sweep all the blobs inside that container, yielding their names as an iterator

```py
def list_folder_names_in_datastore(datastore):
    """ Given a datastore, return an iterator of all the
    names of the folders it contains """
    blob_client = datastore.blob_service  # (1)
    container_client = blob_client.get_container_client(datastore.container_name)  # (2)
    
    for file in container_client.walk_blobs():  # (3)
        yield file.name
```

Now you can iterate through them in search of some name pattern match, or simply show them all by doing

```py
list(list_folder_names_in_datastore(datastore))
# [Out]: ['data/']
```

which is the output that I got, as I only have one folder, `data`, in my datastore:

[image]

The neat thing about this approach is that it does not require any additional imports or connection strings.