# How to pass the datastore URI to azureml.fsspec.AzureMachineLearningFileSystem Python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have registered a datastore which is an ADLS.

```
datastore = mlclient.datastores.get(ds_name)
```

```
from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem

#azureml://subscriptions/<subid>/resourcegroups/<rgname>/workspaces/<workspace_name>/datastore/datastorename
ds_url = f"azureml://subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourcegroups/{RG}/workspaces/{ws_name}/datastore/adls/paths/iris-processed/*"
fs = AzureMachineLearningFileSystem(ds_url)
fs.ls()
```

I am getting the following error even if I use datastore.id:

```
ValueError: azureml://subscriptions/xx/resourcegroups/xx/workspaces/xx/datastore/adls/paths/iris-processed/* is not a valid datastore uri: azureml://subscriptions/([^\/]+)/resourcegroups/([^\/]+)/(?:Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/)?workspaces/([^\/]+)/datastores/([^\/]+)/paths/(.*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ValueError:azureml://subscriptions/xx/resourcegroups/xx/workspaces/xx/datastore/adls/paths/iris-processed/* is not a valid datastoreuri:azureml://subscriptions/([^/]+)/resourcegroups/([^/]+)/(?:Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/)workspaces/([^/]+)/datastores/([^/]+)/paths/(.*)

The above error occurs when you pass the wrong parameters in the URI like (Susbcriptionid, Resource group, Workspace name, Datastore name, and path).

I tried with proper parameters in the Uri with the same code and got the expected results.

Code:

```
from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem

subscription_id = 'Subscription-id'
resource_group = 'Your-resource-group'
workspace_name = 'Workspacename'
input_datastore_name = 'datastore1'
path_on_datastore = 'folder1/'

#azureml://subscriptions/<subid>/resourcegroups/<rgname>/workspaces/<workspace_name>/datastore/datastorename
ds_url =  f'azureml://subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace_name}/datastores/{input_datastore_name}/paths/{path_on_datastore}'
fs = AzureMachineLearningFileSystem(ds_url)
f_list = fs.ls()
print(f_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['datastore1/folder1/09-05-2023 (1).html', 'datastore1/folder1/09-05-2023.html', 'datastore1/folder1/10-05-2023.html', 'datastore1/folder1/10-05=2023.html', 'datastore1/folder1/11-05-2023.html', 'datastore1/folder1/12-05-2023 (1).html', 'datastore1/folder1/12-05-2023.html', 'datastore1/folder1/timezone.csv']
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Is there a way to get list of folders from a datastore in Azure ML studio with Python SDK v2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870455/is-there-a-way-to-get-list-of-folders-from-a-datastore-in-azure-ml-studio-with-p) by khemanth958.

Comment: In the documentation it is given as  /datastore/<ds-name> but it should be /datastores/<ds-name>

Comment: @Venkatesan how do I write a csv to the uri? Happy to post new question.